Have drwxrwxrwx permissions on folder, but after mounting to it it becomes drwxr-xr-x which disalows members of the group to write. How do I fix it?
I have a folder under /mnt/ with drwxrwxrwx permissions and under root:root
I then mount a USB drive (exFAT) to this folder and it becomes drwxr-xr-x
The issue is that now I cannot scp to that folder via WinSCP since there is no permission for group to write to folder, and I am unable to scp as root user.
I am mounting the drive via fstab with the following:
/dev/sdb2       /mnt/USB    exfat   defaults,dmask=0000,umask=0000,rw       0       0

How do I either: 1) Give permission to group write or 2) Mount it as a non root user so that that user can write?
ive attempted chown and chmod to no avail. Chown even when run as root returns Operation not permitted
I am able to write to the mount as root user when in SSH (such as mkdir), so the mount is writable, but only by root.

ExFAT filesystems don't support Unix permissions. The Unix permissions are set at mount time.
The ownership/permissions of the mountpoint (/mnt/USB) has nothing to do with whatever gets mounted over it. It's just a placeholder in the file tree.
To fix it now, try:
sudo mount -o remount,umask=0,dmask=0,fmask=0,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g) /dev/sdb2 /mnt/USB

Update your /etc/fstab entry to add the fmask=0 and uid= and gid= options. You'll have to hard-code your UID and GID, with the values from id -u;id -g.

Thank you, the manual mount worked and after adding fmask and uid and gid to fstab it worked as well. Can you explain what fmask does? also, even though I hardcoded a user, would root still be able to write to it? what about other users?

Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.

Read man mount, search for "mask" (/mask). Read about umask=, dmask=, fmask=).
